# Extra space between text of first and second rows in LaTex tabular environment

Tags: latex, tabular

How to remove the extra space between the text of the first and second rows? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{13em}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{13em}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}}  \hline
    & A & B & C & & D & E & F \\ \hline
Model 1: Name of the first model inserted here & & & & Model 2: Name of the second model inserted here & & & & \\ 
\hspace{3mm} Integration strategies & .03 & .10 & .000 & Integration strategies & .34 & .08 & .000 \\
\hspace{3mm} Integration strategies & .12 & .03 & .56 & Integration strategies & .12 & .19 & .404\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And please don't post code fragments. Add all the things necessary to compile your code.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. I added all the things necessary to compile my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table is defined with 9 columns, but in the second row you use 10. You will get an error about this, so you shouldn't even look at what might or might not be a valid pdf.

If the error is fixed, the table will look like this:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{13em}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{13em}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}}  \hline
    & A & B & C & & D & E & F \\ \hline
Model 1: Name of the first model inserted here & & & & Model 2: Name of the second model inserted here & & & \\ 
\hspace{3mm} Integration strategies & .03 & .10 & .000 & Integration strategies & .34 & .08 & .000 \\
\hspace{3mm} Integration strategies & .12 & .03 & .56 & Integration strategies & .12 & .19 & .404\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of hard-coding the widths of all columns, it might be easier to use the `tabularx` package (and maybe the `booktabs` package for better spacing):

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XlllXlll}  
\toprule
    & A & B & C & & D & E & F \\ 
\midrule
Model 1: Name of the first model inserted here & & & & Model 2: Name of the second model inserted here & & & \\ 
\quad Integration strategies & .03 & .10 & .000 & Integration strategies & .34 & .08 & .000 \\
\quad Integration strategies & .12 & .03 & .56 & Integration strategies & .12 & .19 & .404\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Normally I would also suggest to use `@{}XlllXlll@{}` to remove the space in front and after the columns, but for this specific example, this lead to a really bad linebreak